# How to get product data using productName with the help of API in shopware 6?

Tags: api, shopware

Which structure we can use to get product data using API.

I have tried the below filter but getting multiple product results.

```
{  "search": {
"products": {
    "limit": 1,
    "filter": [
        { "type": "equals", "field": "productNumber", "value": "test_sku" }
    ],
    "sort": [
        { "field": "name", "order": "ASC" }    
    ]
}  }}
```

Thank you in advance..

Comment: do you want to get a product using product's name or number?

Comment: from product number (in shopware its product name but actually it is SKU, unique number)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To search for a product by product number you can use the Admin API or the Store API:

Admin API: `POST /api/search/product`

Store API: `POST /store-api/product`

The filter content is the same for both:

```json
{
    "filter": [
        {
            "type": "equals",
            "field": "productNumber",
            "value": "test_sku"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Above worked, thank tou so much.. I would like to buy a beer for you

Comment: What should be done for fetch perticular order and update tracking.. which api required..

Comment: @Yogesh can you please post a new question? Please be more precise, what field do you want to use to fetch an order (order number?) and what do you want to update (tracking code?).

Comment: you can check here.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68270661/how-we-can-update-shopware-6-order-using-api